# Why is the flag "declined"

Tags: support, flagging, declined-flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977280/which-int-type-does-var-default-to) for migration to Stack Overflow, and it has been successfully migrated. However, the status of the corresponding flag in my profile is "declined". Is this a bug?

Comment: Retagged this to [support] as your flag was declined by a fellow mod (so, no bug). I responded to a flag that came after yours, and agreed with you and the other flagger that the question would be more suitable for Stack Overflow than Programmers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I must have declined the flag in error because I can't for the life of me think of why I would have done this any other way.

I apologize for the mistake and hope it didn't inconvenience you.